# How to set up password check on unmounting NTFS partitions?

Tags: mount, nautilus, ntfs, fstab, automount

I have dual boot PC laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. My PC has two hard drivers:

`/dev/sda` - that is SSD drive containing Windows C: NTFS partition and Ubuntu / and swap filesystems.

`/dev/sdb` - that is traditional hard disk drive containing Windows D: NTFS partition

**I want to have both of my NTFS partitions mounted automatically and read-only.**
Ubuntu 14.04 automatically mounts both NTFS partitions, but read-write, which is not exactly what I want. So I created mount directories under `/media` and added the following lines to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# Windows C: /dev/sda1
UUID=2EF64975F6493DF9   /media/win_c    ntfs    defaults,umask=222      0  0
# Windows D: /dev/sdb1
UUID=50C40C08C40BEED2   /media/win_d    ntfs    defaults,umask=222      0  0
```

Now both NTFS partition are mounted automatically and read-only. However, I observed a strange behavior in Nautilus, that I want to correct.

**First, the C: partition has different icon than D: partition; moreover, C: partition is attached to Launcher, while D: is not. Why?**

Second, I can unmount C: partition by clicking on eject icon, but if I want to unmount D: partition the same way, I am asked of password. I like the password check here, so I want to have the same for C:. **Why there is a difference between C: and D: partition behavior? What should I put into my `/etc/fstab` to have Nautilus ask of password when unmounting C: partition as well?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found explanation myself. It turned out that Ubuntu does some voodoo magic around file systems mounted in the `/media` directory. So in the `/etc/fstab` file I changed mount points from `/media` to `/mnt` as follows:

```
# Windows C: /dev/sda1
UUID=2EF64975F6493DF9   /mnt/win_c    ntfs    auto,ro      0  0
# Windows D: /dev/sdb1
UUID=50C40C08C40BEED2   /mnt/win_d    ntfs    auto,ro      0  0
```

Now both NTFS partitions are mounted automatically and read-only on system boot, and both require administrator password to unmount, which is exactly what I wanted to have.

However, there is no any quick access icons for them in the Nautilus, but this is rather unimportant detail than real problem.